Can't login after nvidia driver update Ubuntu 20.04
I've updated the Nvidia driver using its .run file. Before that, I run the --uninstall to uninstall the previous version. The new installation went fine. However, after restarting the machine, the screen is extremely zoomed and what I see are just a few pixels from the cursor. I'm not even able to login.
Any suggestion on how to fix this?
Thank you!

You will be far better off sticking to the Nvidia drivers offered in Ubuntu via the standard repos (Software&Updates universe, multiverse,..etc.) or the graphics-drivers PPA for the latest drivers. kernel updates tend not to successfully rebuild the nvidia modules without the Ubuntu "glue" code to do that.

This question is similar to: Nvidia Geforce GT 710 Driver Installation. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
